# Regular Expressions/globs on token lists instead of strings

Tags: python, regex, glob

So I have a list of tokens, which we can pretend is a list of strings for simplicity:

```
["hello", "world", "this", "is", "some", "interesting", "input"]
```

I want to be able to write a pattern, which ideally looks something like a regular expression and gives me the complete strength of a regex engine, but if I just have glob-style wildcards that's fine too.

So if I have a pattern (with an imagined syntax where things that start with `$` are named wildcards) like so:

```
["hello", "$part1", "some", "$part2"]
```

I want to be able to run it on the input above, see that it matches, and be able to get `["world", "this", "is"]` for `$part1` and `["interesting", "input"]` for `$part2`.

I could encode my token list as a string, compile my pattern token list into a plain old regex pattern, and just use a regex. But my token list doesn't actually contain strings, it contains token objects that have metadata that I don't want to lose.

My current direction is implementing my own custom regex engine following [Russ Cox's article](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) on NFAs, and that will definitely work, but that is rather complex.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: I ended up just writing the NFA. It worked great.

Comment: Why didn't the simpler way work? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose your token list is:

```
['a', 'b', 'cx', 'cy']
```

You can easily map it into the string:

```
'<0><1><2><3>'
```

Then you have a pattern like:

```
['a', '<token>*', 'c.*']
```

You can map the pattern into the regex:

```
'<0>(.*)<(2|3)>'
```

The `2|3` can be found with `'|'.join(str(i) for i, token in enumerate(tokens) if re.match('c.*', token))`. (Or with faster indexing/caching depending on your needs.)

Then just use any functions for regular expressions.